# Most efficient way of finding common subexpressions in a list of strings in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have a list of strings that represents package directories. I want to iterate the list, to find largest part of the strings where the packages are the same, then extract this substring, subtract that from the original list of strings to get specific packages so I create the appropriate directories.

I was thinking of creating the original list as a static hash set, then using the retainAll method, storing the result in a new String.

Would something like this be the most performant option, or is there a better way to do it?

Many thanks

Comment: So if I get you right you have two strings and need to find their longest common substring? Please add example input and expected output to get better answers

Comment: will all the strings have a common prefix? And are you looking for the longest prefix all have in common?

Comment: Apologies,

I will have strings that would have the format of : "aa.bb.cc.serverside", "aa.bb.cc.clientSide" etc, where the package hierarchy could be of variable depth. In this example, I would want to extract "aa.bb.cc", then remove all instances of "aa.bb.cc" from the original set of strings. Once done, I can then do something like makeDirectory(removedString + specificBit).

@jlordo, the prefix will be similar to a point, but will vary depending on the function of the class it will generate. I need to find that point, then remove it from all the strings so I get the specific bit out.

Comment: So for the whole list of packages, do you only need to extract a SINGLE most common root package?

Comment: @JohnB, yes basically. Then that can be used to remove it from each other string

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, explanation in comments

```
// returns the length of the longest common prefix of all strings in the given array 
public static int longestCommonPrefix(String[] strings) {
    // Null or no contents, return 0
    if (strings == null || strings.length == 0) {
        return 0;
        // only 1 element? return it's length
    } else if (strings.length == 1 && strings[0] != null) {
        return strings[0].length();
        // more than 1
    } else {
        // copy the array and sort it on the lengths of the strings,
        // shortest one first.
        // this will raise a NullPointerException if an array element is null 
        String[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(strings, strings.length);
        Arrays.sort(copy, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return o2.length() - o1.length();
            }
        });
        int result = 0; // init result
        // iterate through every letter of the shortest string
        for (int i = 0; i < copy[0].length(); i++) { 
            // compare the corresponding char of all other strings
            char currenChar = copy[0].charAt(i);
            for (int j = 1; j < strings.length; j++) {                  
                if (currenChar != copy[j].charAt(i)) { // mismatch
                    return result;
                }
            }
            // all match
            result++;
        }
        // done iterating through shortest string, all matched.
        return result;
    }
}
```

If changing the original array does not bother you, you can omit the line `String[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(strings, strings.length);` and just sort your `strings` array.

To retrieve the text, change the return type to `String` and return something like `return copy[0].substring(0, result + 1);` within the loop and `return copy[0];` at the end of the method.

Comment: He needs the text of the longest common prefix. This means that a `String` is required. Your method returns an `int`.

Comment: The text can easily be extracted with a substring method

Comment: Ah, so the `int` is the index of the last most common character.

Comment: yes, it is the length of the longest common substring ;) i edited my answer, now explaining how to get the string he is looking for

Comment: Smart to sort by length to start, but the problem I see is that this solution iterates the list of packages n times where n is the length of the smallest package. This does not seem efficient and the question specifically asked for an efficient solution.

Comment: Cheers for the feedback everyone. Will have a think and a play and see what falls out.

My thanks to you all

Comment: @JohnB regarding efficiency: I know I iterate over the packages n times, but I only compare 1 char at a time, thus having n * |packages| comparisons (worst case: shortest is prefix of all others). Your solution only iterates the packages once, but you compare the whole reference string with all others. That's at least n comparisons per pair. Overall you will have about n * |packages| comparisons, too. Could be more, if your reference is one of the long ones...

Comment: True, I am assuming / hoping that Java might have some efficiencies built into contains. Of course you know what happens when you "assume". Cheers!

Comment: This will be even less efficient ;) look at [String implementation](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html). (Thx for +1)

Comment: Hey guys,

Really appreciated all the feedback, I have implemented something similar to what @jlordo suggested, but used split to create tokens based on the dots in each string, then compared each token rather than individual characters.

Much love

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for the single most common package, I would do the following:

Grab the first element from the list (call it the reference package). Using this package name I would iterate through the list. For each remaining element in the list, see if the element contains the reference package. If so move to the next element. If not trim your reference package by one package (taking `aa.bb.cc.serverside` and converting to `aa.bb.cc`). Then see if the current element contains this new reference package. Repeat this until the reference package is empty or until the element matches. Then continue down the list of packages.

This will give you the largest most common package. Loop back through removing this from all elements in the list.

EDIT: Slight modification, better keep the `.` at the end of the package name to ensure complete package name.

Answer (score 0):

Just sort them. The common prefixes will appear first.